# How do I prove orthogonality if the lengths of two vectors are equal?

Tags: calculus, vectors, orthonormal

If $||v|| = ||w||$, how can we show $(v + w)$ and $(v - w)$ are orthogonal?

I can't find a way to show $(v + w) * (v + (- w)) = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(v+w)\cdot (v-w)= v\cdot v - v\cdot w + w\cdot v - w\cdot w = \Vert v \Vert^2 - v\cdot w + w\cdot v - \Vert w \Vert ^2 $$
But $ \Vert v \Vert^2 =  \Vert w \Vert^2$ and $w\cdot v = v\cdot w$ so
$$(v+w)\cdot (v-w) = 0$$

Comment: wow it was right there. this was great thanks alot! I didn't know vector dot products where equivalent to foiling it out this way?

Comment: welcome ;) glad it was helpful @Jaigus

Comment: @Jaigus you can think of a dot product as matrix multiplication with $x \cdot y = x^Ty$ with $x^T$ the transpose of $x$ and all vectors column vectors. This can often simplify arguments involving orthogonality and reveal otherwise mysterious properties of the dot product.

Comment: Yes as @CyclotomicField is saying, if your numbers are real, then you could think about it as $x.y$ as $x^T y$

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks to both of you.